# Form doesn't work with select?

Tags: html, angularjs

The form doesn't accept a `select`. When I comment `select` section, all is ok. Where did I make a mistake?

```
 <form ng-submit="submitForm()">
     <select ng-model="selectedMedication" style="display: block" 
 ng-options="medication.name for medication in data2" ng-model = "newPrescription.medication_name">
     </select>          
 <input type="date" class="datepicker" ng-model = "newPrescription.start_date">
   <label for="datepicker">Start date</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Better yet, post a [plunker](http://plnkr.co).

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 ng-model directives on your select...

Comment: It looks like you should remove the selectedMedication one. Since you are binding the other item to newPrescription

Comment: ok, but form doesn't work. again

Comment: Can you add more of your html/js? Do you see any errors in the console?